# Why is an extension $\bar \phi : F(x) \rightarrow F(a)$ an isomorphism if $\phi : F[x] \to F(a)$ is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Why is $\bar \phi : F(x) \rightarrow F(a)$ an isomorphism given  $\phi : F[x] \rightarrow F(a)$ satisfy $\ker \phi = \{0\}$ ?

I've been trying to figure out why $\bar \phi$ is an isomorphism, and why $\phi$ is not an isomorphism.

I know that since $\ker \phi = \{0\}$ it follows that $\phi$ is one-to-one (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Now we only need to show $\overline{\phi}$ is surjective in order to show $\overline{\phi}$ is an isomorphism $F(x) \rightarrow F(a)$.

How can I see that $\bar \phi$ is an isomorphism $F(x) \rightarrow F(a)$? And why can I extend a one-to-one homomorphism on the polynomial ring to achieve this result?

OBS: $F(a)$ denote the smallest subfield of $E$ that contains $F$ and $\{a\}$.

[image]

Comment: Hint: try to use the universal property of the fraction field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map you're looking at is evaluation at a point, $a$. There are two cases:

**Case 1:** $a$ is algebraic over $F$, in which case, there is a polynomial , $p(x)\in F[x]$ such that $p(a)=0$ showing that $\phi$ is not injective since it sends $F[x]\ni p(x)\to 0$.

**Case 2:** $a$ is transcendental. Then let ${p(x)\over q(x)}\in\ker \overline{\phi}$ be in reduced form for some polynomials $p,q\in F[x]$. This implies

> $$\overline{\phi}\left({p(x)\over q(x)}\right)={\phi(p(x))\over\phi(q(x))}={p(a)\over q(a)}=0\iff p(a)=0$$

Since $a$ is transcendental, $p(x)=0$, the zero polynomial, hence the kernel is trivial. On the other hand, this part of the proof has given us a vital clue:

Let $y={p(a)\over q(a)}\in F(a)$*, since $a$ transcendental, $q(a)\ne 0$ when $q\ne 0$ (here's where we use injectivity), but then $\overline{\phi}(p(x)/q(x))={\phi(p(x))\over\phi(q(x))}=y$ so that $\overline{\phi}$ is surjective.

---

*Note that since $F(a)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$, we can see that we can get all rational functions in $a$ with coefficients in $F$ in $F(a)$ because those are the things we can make using $F$, $a$, and the field operations, $\cdot, +, -, \div$, but also those are the **only** operations we're allowed, so all elements of $F(a)$ are rational functions in $a$ with coefficients in $F$, so that every $y$ has the claimed form.

Comment: How do you know you can write $y = \frac {p(a)} {q(a)}$ for all $y \in F(a)$ ?

Comment: Definition of $F(a)$ is $F$-rational functions in $a$.

Comment: The definition I know is: $F(a)$ denote the smallest subfield of $E$ that contains $F$ and $\{a\}$. Can I conclude the same ?

Comment: Yes, all fields are closed under multiplication, addition, and division, so all rational functions in the variable are in there as well. Because if $a\in F(a)$ then I can form powers of $a$ because $F(a)$ is a field, and then I can add up $F$-linear combinations of those powers because $F(a)$ is a field, then I can divide those polynomials into one another because $F(a)$ is a field.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I've also added a note at the end on why all $y\in F(a)$ have the form I claimed. It's just the axioms for a field, because anything you can form using the field operations, $+,-,\cdot, \div$ and the elements from $F$ and $a$ are rational functions with $F$ and $a$. Since $F$ is a field, any rational function of elements of $F$ is just another element of $F$, so you don't get anything new there, only with $a$ is anything added.

Comment: Is it because if $b \in F(a)$ has the property $b \notin F \cup  \{a\}$ it must be the case that $b$ is of the form $c_n a^n + ... + c_1 a + c_0$ for $c_i \in F$ ? Why is this neccesarily true ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen 1) You mean a ratio of things in that form, not something in that form.
2) The reason is it's the *definition* of being a field, it's not something you have to prove, it's literally *given* to you on a platter as axioms for a field, it's a set that is closed under those operations, so the **smallest** field containing the set $F\cup\{a\}$ is made up of only the things that *have* to be there based on the axioms, which are

$${c_na^n+\ldots +c_1a+c_0\over d_ma^m+\ldots +d_1a+d_0}$$

with $c_i, d_i\in F$.

Comment: Thank you Adam. By the way can $\phi : F[x] \rightarrow F(a)$ be an isomorphism given that $a$ is transcendental ?

Comment: No, you need to do it on $F(x)$, otherwise you won't be able to hit things like $a^{-1}\in F(a)$. In fact, $F[x]\to F(a)$ is an isomorphism iff $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: Why can't I hit $a^{-1}$ ? I know $\phi(x) = a$. So if I could hit $a^{-1}$, I would have an inverse of $x$ in $F[x]$, which is impossible ?

Comment: $a^{-1}$ is the image of $x^{-1}$ when $a$ is transcendental, you cannot hit it with something else because $\overline{\phi}$ is injective, so each image has a unique pre-image. If $a$ is algebraic, then it has a polynomial

$$c_0+c_1a+\ldots +c_na^n=0\iff 1=-{1\over c_0}(c_na^n+\ldots + c_1a)$$
$$\iff a\cdot\bigg(-{1\over c_0}(c_na^{n-1}+\ldots +c_2a+c_1)\bigg)=1$$

so that $a^{-1}=-{1\over c_0}(c_na^{n-1}+\ldots +c_2a+c_1)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi$ is injective, then $\bar{\phi}$ simply exchanges $x$ for $a$ in any rational function of $x$. This has an obvious inverse map: exchange $a$ back for the element $x$. Note that $F[x]\to F(a)$ cannot be an isomorphism if $a$ is transcendental, since e.g. $a^{-1}$ has no preimage. A noninjective $\phi$ fails to induce a map $F(x)\to F[a]$ in the first place, since $\phi(1/f(x))$ would be ill-defined if $f(x)\in\ker\phi$.

Comment: How do you know $a^{-1}$ has no preimage ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Have you tried thinking about it?